# iOS Storyboard - creating customized UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell via Storyboard for my iPhone App (Note: this is iOS 7).

Each cell is a bit complicated, consisting of a UIView with a few labels. In other words, I want to set up a prototype cell by customizing the content view of the cell itself.

Here are the steps I tried:

1. Drag a UIView into the Table View in Storyboard and set it's tag to be 1.
2. Added a single label to that UIView (ultimately, I will need several labels).
3. Implemented some basic table view methods:

As follows:

```
-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIView *view = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSLog(@"%@",view); //this just prints "(null)" a bunch of times

    return cell;
}
```

Here's the hierarchy of my GUI elements.

[image]

Here is a demonstration that I have set the tag of the UIView to 1.

[image]

And here is the UITableView:

[image]

It prints out `(null)` many times. What is the proper way to do this? I haven't had success finding any tutorials for complex custom `UITableViewCells` that are built through storyboard.

Comment: `1.` You need to use a prototype cell (a `UITableViewCell` not a `UIView`) and `2.`You need to create an IBOutlet back from the label to the view controller; then you can set the text (e.g. `self.myLabel.text = @"Hello"` and remove your UIView line.  This is very basic iOS coding. If you are having difficulty, I recommend you follow some of the tutorials on Ray Wenderlich's site (http://www.raywenderlich.com) or better yet use iTunesU to look at the latest Stanford iOS 7 course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to drag and drop `UITableViewCell` to your `UITableView` not `UIView`.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Ah! Didn't even see that. Okay, so then how would I structure my cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: That method should stay as it is. You do not need to check for `nil` as it should always be not null. Make sure you set cell identifier in the storyboard.